# How to read the data of the row when clicked the button in the same row

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have the data displayed in the grid as follows:

StartDate  Enddate          Button

16/3/2013   17/3/2013      Signup---> this is an ASP button

18/3/2013  19/3/2012       Signup----> this is an ASP button

20/3/2012  20/3/2012       Signup----> this is an ASP button

I want asp.net with c# code when i clicked on first row signup button i want to get the data of the first row. If clicked on second row i want only the data of the second row startdate and end time. How can i acheive this? Please hep me in this regard.

Comment: Can you provide what your page code looks like to be sure you get an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the asp button, Set properties: CommandName="SignUp" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'

Now, when this button is clicked it calls Gridview's RowCommand Event

In that event e.CommandArgument contains your Row Number.

GridViewRow gvr= gvLinkImages.Rows[e.CommandArgument];

Now you can use gvr.Cells[column number] to get the particular text (Not recommended)
or use findcontrol to get the label or literal of the start/end date( assuming you are using Templatefields)
Sample code below

**C#**

```
protected void gvResults_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "SignUp") 
     {
    int rwNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gvr = gvResults.Rows(rwNumber);

    System.DateTime rowStartDate = default(System.DateTime);
    System.DateTime rowEndDate = default(System.DateTime);

    //If you are using Templatefields
    Literal lblRowStartDate = gvr.FindControl("lblStartDate") as Literal;
    Literal lblRowEndDate = gvr.FindControl("lblEndDate") as Literal;
    rowStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblRowStartDate.Text);
    rowEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblRowEndDate.Text);

    //Incase you are not using TemplateFields or Autobinding your grid
    rowStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvr.Cells[0].Text);
    rowEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvr.Cells[1].Text);

}
}
```

**ASPX**

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvResults" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvResults_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblStartDate" Text='<%#Container.DataItem.StartDate%>'></asp:Literal>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblStartDate" Text='<%#Container.DataItem.EndDate%>'></asp:Literal>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignUp" CommandName="SignUp" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"  />

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I tried th ebelow and works like charm Below is the code if (e.CommandName == "SignUp")
                {
                    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
                    EndDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);
                    Control ctl = e.CommandSource as Control;